# How to integrate admob native ads in eclipse

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I have a project where i am integrating Admob BANNER, INSTERSTITIAL and Native ads. I can integrate INTERSTITIAL and BANNER. but i dont know how to integrate NATIVE ADS. 
I am working in eclipse
below is how  i am integrating interstitial and banner.

```
          final InterstitialAd interstitial;
     //(((((((((( ADMOB Banner Ads )))))))
        AdView adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);            
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);


interstitial = new InterstitialAd(activity);
interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-5900269475646349/1619195915");

//AdRequest  adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

 interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
    {
        // Listen for when user closes ad
        public void onAdClosed() 
        {
             //Load Interesterial add
             // AdRequest  adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
           //  .build();
         //    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest); 

        }

        public void onAdLoaded() 
        {
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express GitHub: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob

Comment: @DanielStorm ,those guidlines are incorrect for eclipse

Answer (score 1):

To add native ads you have to use the latest googleplayservices lib.

To use it you have to add all projects in 
`Sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\` as projects.
I mean, extract , e.g. , `play-services-10.2.0.aar` as archive and add it into eclipse as library project. Do it with `Sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-ads-lite\10.2.0\` too.